# How to Select only some properties from a OneToMany Collection in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

### TL;DR

How can I get a single A object with only a few properties in a B collection?

### Explanation

I am working on a legacy project where people had the brillant idea to map every relationship as EAGER.

Now, we are having performance problems.

For instance, I have Class A, that has a list of B objects. That list has been mapped as a bag in hibernate, and loads lazily (so far, so good). The problem is, B eagerly loads the whole freaking alphabet:

**A.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class="A" table="a" lazy="false">
        // properties
        <bag name="listOfBs" inverse="true">
            <key column="a_id" [...]>
            <one-to-many class="B" />
        </bag>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**B.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class="B" table="b" lazy="false">
        <many-to-one name="a" class="A" column="a_id" />
        // lots of other many-to-one mappings

        // properties

        // lots of one-to-many properties
</hibernate-mapping>
```

So I need only 4 properties of B, but it fetches every related object!

In order to solve this without breaking everything, I am trying to use a hql query to select only a few column of the collection:

```
"select a, b.field1, b.field2, b.field3, b.field4
 from A a inner join B b where a.id = :id"
```

But I need an Unique Result, so the following query causes an exception.

Comment: Can you use Criteria API ? If possible you can set result transformer to the criteria. In this case AliasToBeanConstructorResultTransformer would work

Comment: @SAP nice! I can set a ResultTransformer to a query too, I'll try that. Post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it in case it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I needed using two queries. One to fetch object A, another one to populate the list of B objects. I guess one can do the same using two Criterias and Projections.

First, I created a new constructor in class B:

```
class B {
    public B(String field1, String field2, String field3, String field4) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.field3 = field3;
        this.field4 = field4;
    }
}
```

Then, I created the queries:

```
public A fetch(Integer id) {
    // try-catch abstracted
    Query query = getSession.createQuery("from A a where a.id = :id");
    query.setParameter("id", id);

    A a = (A) query.uniqueResult();

    query = getSession().createQuery("select new B(b.field1, b.field2, b.field3, b.field4) from B where b.A.id = :id");
    query.setParameter("id", id);

    List<B> bs = query.list();

    a.setListOfBs(bs);

    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set result transformer after converting above SQL into a criteria. In this case AliasToBeanConstructorResultTransformer would work

First create a class to contain result columns from criteria,

```
public class ResultPresenter{

private String a;
private String bField1;
private Integer bField2;
private String bField3;
private String bField4;

public ResultPresenter(String a, String bField1, Integer bField2, String bField3, String bField4){

this.a = a;
this.bField1 = bField1;
this.bField2 = bField2;
this.bField3 = bField3;
this.bField4 = bField4;
}
}
```

set projections for required columns,

```
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
createProjectionList.add(projections.property(a));
createProjectionList.add(projections.property(b.field1));
createProjectionList.add(projections.property(b.field2));
createProjectionList.add(projections.property(b.field3));
createProjectionList.add(projections.property(b.field4));
```

set AliasToBeanConstructorResultTransformer to the criteria,

```
java.lang.reflect.Constructor cons = ResultPresenter.class.getConstructor(Arrays.asList(new Class[]{String.class, String.class, Integer.class, String.class, String.class}));

criteria.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanConstructorResultTransformer(cons));
```

Comment: hi, sorry! I tried your solution but it gave me a PropertyAccessException... I tried mapping the aliases as well, but I got the same result. I guess it's not that simple after all.

Comment: hi, either I implemented it wrong, or something was missing... Anyway, I've solved it using two queries. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Please mention the order-by in set tag of hbm.

```
<set name="subCompanies" lazy="false" order-by="lower(companyName)">
            ------------------------------
            ------------------------------          
</set>
```